# Jupyter notebook markdown highlight options

Tags: jupyter-notebook, markdown

I would like to type highlight in jupyter notebook, such as:
[image]

How could I highlight as this?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the question is about. I think what you're looking for is [Markdown sintax](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/jupyter/notebook/blob/master/docs/source/examples/Notebook/Working%20With%20Markdown%20Cells.ipynb), you can just use

```
The `numpy.array` type provides a handy method, `item`,
```

inside a markdown cell to get

[image: Markdown example]

The differences in appearance from the example you shared are relative to a different engine used for rendering. If you want to obtain a specific style, instated, markdown cells support HTML that allow you to customize the output. For instance using

```
The <span style='color: #e74c3c; font-family: monospace; background-color: #F7F2F4;'>numpy.array</span> type provides a handy method, <span style='color: #e74c3c; font-family: monospace; background-color: #F7F2F4;'>item</span>,
```

you will get

[image: appearence]

Hope this was helpful :)